# unexpected '<' in an empty line

Tags: php, html

```
<head>

    <title>Login</title>
    <?php

        if($verhalten == 1) 
        {
            /* The important line */
    ?>

        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=seite2.php"/>

    <?php

        }

    ?>

</head>
```

...

This is my code in general. The problem is that PHP is telling me that there is an unexpected '<' in line 38 (the line that i marked) even though the line is completly empty. Ive read through the other questions, but none of them seem to be helping me. Its prolly just a dumb mistake, but it would be quite nice of you to tell me where it is, because i have no idea where it could be.

Comment: Is this example failing as well? If not, keep adding your original stuff and testing, until it breaks again. It probably is - as you also write - some dumb mistake. But those sure can take a long time to find sometimes.

Comment: Ive played around with it for an hour. The error always occures in the same line. How am i supposed to recognize a mistake in an empty line. I double checked everything and i closed it all properly. I think ive just gotta wait some more time, maybe someone finds the mistake :)

Comment: Add another line and see if the error now is in line 39. If it is not, then somehow you're not editing the file that you see (your FTP location may point somewhere else, the page might be cached, etc...).

Comment: It was all weird and stuff. I somehow didnt edited the file in my htdocs but rather the one on my desktop i created 1st of all it. Thanks anyway bud, really helped me out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do.  This should't throw any errors.

```
<head>

<title>Login</title>
<?php

    if($verhalten == 1) 
    {
      echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=seite2.php"/>';
    }
?>
</head>
```

Comment: You can exit PHP during `if`-blocks to parse HTML instead - provided you enter PHP again to close the bracket, so the code OP posted is actually valid.

Comment: @Qirel Really.  Never knew that:)  Thanks for letting me know!